# Fuse.js exact search and fuzzy search not working correct when searchedText has more length

Tags: reactjs, fuse.js

I was trying Fuse.js for searching in react.js web application. I need to have exact search when exact value is searched and fuzzy search when no exact value present.

```
const data = [{"title": "Test-One-123-E99384384384384HSNNS8789"},{"title": "Test-One-123-E99384384384384HSNNS8786"},{"title": "Test-One-123-E99384384384384HSNNS8784"}];

const keys = ["title"];

const fuseOptions = {
keys,
threshold:0.5,
includeScore: true,
ignoreLocation: true,
distance:100
}

const dataFuse = new Fuse(data, fuseOptions);
const items = query ? dataFuse.search(query).map(({item}) => item) : data;
```

If I search "Test-One-123-E99384384384384HSNNS8789" I should only get 1 object but in this case I am getting all 3 objects. This code is working fine if the title length is less. Its failing only when title is longer.

Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

You likely get all results because of the partial matches of the substring `E99384384384384HSNNS878`. You can sort the results by the `score` which should already provide the highest ranking for your expected item.